# Loading an external SWF file into a loader movie and type casting to MovieClip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to import a SWF file into a custom loader and then treat the loaded SWF file as a MovieClip object. The code for the functionality can be seen below.

```
public function loadMyMovie(movie:String)
{

    var now:Date = new Date();

    var rnd:String = "?randomize=" + now.time;

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(movie);

    request.data = getObjectURLVariables(this.loaderInfo.parameters)

    var loading:Loader = new Loader();

    loading.load(request);

    loading.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);

    function loadComplete(event:Event):void {

        var movie:MovieClip = addChild(loading.content);

        movie.gotoAndStop(0);

    }

}
```

When I do this I get the following error.

> Implicit coercion of a value with static type
>   flash.display:DisplayObject to a possibly unrelated type
>   flash.display:MovieClip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the SWF file I was attempting to import was AS2, so it was being imported as a AVM1Movie object. Need to speak with the developer who produced the SWF.

Answer (score 0):

You make can try this.
 `var movie:DisplayObject = event.target.content as DisplayObject;`
 AVM1Movie is not a DisplayObjectContainer.

Comment: I need to be able to control how the imported SWF is played, so I am going to have to get the developer of the SWF to amend his code or to rebuild it in AS3.